# How to add css to only first 3 unordered list and not to ordered list?

Tags: html, css, list, web, frontend

Suppose there is html code as below

```
<ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   <ol>
       <li>3.14</li>
    </ol>
</ul>
```

I wanted to change text color of first three unordered list to red and not to make any changes in ordered list using css.

Comment: Before looking at the CSS, please modify your HTML so it is legal (ol cannot be a child of ul, did you mean to put it in a li element?).

Comment: @AHaworth Hi, I think its possible ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul#ordered_list_inside_unordered_list

Comment: Look carefully at their code, the ol is contained within an li, you can't have an ol as a direct child of a ul. Do you want the ol to be in an li in that ul or do you want it to be separate after the ul?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you may use child selectors:

```
ul>li:first-child {
color:red;
}

ul>li:nth-child(2) {
color:red;
}

ul>li:nth-child(3) {
  color:red;
}

ol li {
  color:blue;
}
```

If you have multiple ul list , then you may add classes so that the css won't affect others.

`ol li` is added because if `ol` falls under `li`, then, when you apply color to `li` it will also modify the color of ol. So to prevent it we have to explicitly give desired color to `ol' li.`

Comment: @Dalvik This css doesnt give me exact styling.

Comment: Glad to help @AdithyaBaliga, If it helps you could you please upvote and accept it as an answer, so that others can get benefit to of it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Dalvik asking for upvotes doesn't seem correct

Comment: After the edit it will now style li inside the ul AND inside the ol

Comment: Correction: after the second edit is is now correct and the same as my already existing answer.

Comment: @JohannesH. you are not the only person who knows about dependent selectors.

Comment: @Dalvik Yes I have voted for second edit answer

Comment: Never claimed I am. It's just pointless to edit an answer that was originally completely different to be exactly the same as an existing one. You could've just deleted it.

Comment: @AdithyaBaliga I've updated the fidle https://jsfiddle.net/byzmr62x/

Comment: I gave the exactly correct answer what the OP was wanted, it just the thing the I miss spelled the tag. Also once you pointed I corrected it. There was no point of posting another answer and boasting about that answer.

Comment: was Background color mention in Question I didn't found any clue About BG Color so I have the logic for just to change text color mention if Question deals with BG Color??

Comment: no @Yashchitroda, I just provided the path... and see he is able to solve it.

Comment: @Yashchitroda did he mentioned to solve the problem using class ?

Comment: @Dalvik I just edited my question to text color for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

### Create 2 Files

> #### index.html

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <ul class="i">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   </ul>

   <ol>
   <li>3.14</li>
</ol>
```

> #### style.css

```
.i{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Adithya Baliga Does it solves your Problem??

Comment: This has altered the HTML without comment - is it what the OP wants as the structure (it may be, we don't know).

Comment: @Yashchitroda I wanted external css and no css in HTML code

Comment: Style attribute does require you to repeat every style property for every element, which is pain when doing changes later. They also break precedence as they override everything.  Classes work better.

Comment: @Adithya Baliga Does this one solves your Problem Now ??

Comment: @Yashchitroda My question was not to alter anything in html and only do some css to achieve this

Comment: @Adithya Baliga is my answer helpful to your Question??

Comment: @Yashchitroda I think its same as previous edit as I already said no modification in HTML code only css stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS child selectors and combine them with direct descendant selectors so they only apply to `li` directly inside `ul` and not further down.

```
ul > li:nth-child(1), ul > li:nth-child(2), ul > li:nth-child(3) {
... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 3 li element, we can apply css of all 3 li element like this:-

```
ul>li{
    color:red;
    some more properties;
}
```